# Swift View and Controller shared variable initialization troubles

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, initialization, swift2

I'm porting some code from Objc to Swift. And struggling with Swift's initialization life cycle. From a simplified point of view, there are 4 players I'm trying to bring into play here:

1. An object called a `Program`. This is my main top level model object at this point. The remaining 3 players all want access to an instance of him.
2. A `ProgramEditController`, painted in my main Main.storyboard. He's responsible for instantiating an initial Program, which cannot be done directly as a property initializer.
3. A top level custom UIView subclass, called `ProgramTimelineView`. Painted in the Main.storyboard, manages a variety of specialized subviews. Linked to a property of my ViewController. Has properties for the it's subviews as well. It wants access to the Program, so it can do layout and pass it on to subviews.
4. A particular subview of `ProgramTimelineView` called `ProgramGridView`. These are not painted in the XCode canvas tool, but directly instantiated by the containing `ProgramTimelineView`. It wants access to the Program. Uses it to do his custom `drawRect`.

Here's the relevant code for my Controller:

```
class ProgramEditController: UIViewController { 
    // MARK: - Variables
    @IBOutlet var timelineView:ProgramTimelinesView!

    var site = Site()

    var program:Program!

    // MARK: - Initialize

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // set up the new program
        self.program = self.site.newProgram() 
        // get it into our top view before it starts drawing
        self.timelineView.program = self.program 
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) // Why does Swift make me have a redundant thing here?
    }

}
```

And for ProgramTimelinesView:

```
class ProgramTimelinesView: UIView {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var gridView = ProgramGridView()

    var program:Program! {
        didSet {
            self.gridView.program = self.program
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    func addGridView() {
        self.gridView.alpha = 0.0
        self.gridView.opaque = false
        self.addSubview(self.gridView)
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.addGridView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

}
```

And finally for the `ProgramGridView`:

```
class ProgramGridView: TimeAxisView {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var program:Program!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // access self.program in here
    }
}
```

What I thought would happen:

1. `ProgramEditController.init(nibName...)` would fire first.
2. The super call would cause my `ProgramTimelineView.init(coder)` to fire.
3. ProgramTimelineView instance would first call the `gridView` initializer setting it to a new `ProgramGridView` view
4. The remainder of `ProgramTimelineView.init(coder)` would run, which would add the gridView into the view tree.
5. Control would return to the `ProgramEditController.init(nibName)` initializers. The controller's `program` property would be populated.
6. The bound `timelineView` would have its `program` property set.
7. `ProgramTimelineView` would in turn set the `program` property of the `gridView`.

What seems to happen though, between steps 4 and 5, is that a `drawRect()` happens. That causes a seg fault, because the gridView's program has not been set yet! But why is it issuing drawRect()'s at this point? I thought that wouldn't happen before all of the initializers had fired. But clearly some side affect is occurring. What is the correct pattern/idiom to employ to avoid this? I really would rather not turn all of the `program!` into `program?` and then put let/guards every where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There turned out to be a faulty assumption in my original premises (usually the case).

`UIViewController.init(nib...)` is NOT called when creating from interface builder assets. But local variables linked in interface builder (implicitly wrapped) are not set/realized at the point of `init(coder)` either. The correct approach required two adjustments:

1. Move the setup of the `program` var to the `init(coder)` initializers:

e.g.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.program = self.site.newProgram()
}
```

2. Forward that to the view in a `viewDidLoad()` override.

e.g.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timelineView.program = self.program
}
```